# Laravel How to add orderBy on categorized posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a `laravel`-application where I have a Blog section. The posts are split up into categories so that the user can switch between each categories. So far so good but since I added the categorization and I click the "All"-tab, the `orderBy()`-method does not work anymore. Instead, the posts appear under their respective category, ignoring the `orderBy`-method.

Here is my controller:

```
$blogs = QueryBuilder::for(Blog::class)
   ->allowedFilters([
       AllowedFilter::exact('category', 'blog_category_id'),
   ])
   ->orderBy('publishes_on', 'desc')
   ->where("publishes_on", "<=", Carbon::now())
   ->where('blog_status_id', '=', '2')
   ->with('blog_category', 'employee')
   ->get();


$blog_categories = BlogCategory::get();


return view('blog.index', compact('blogs', 'blog_categories'));
```

then in my view:

```
// the tab menu - click events handled with Javascript
<ul>
   <li data-tab-id="all" class="tab all active">All</li>
     @foreach ($blog_categories as $category)
      <li data-tab-id="{{ strtolower($category->name) }}" class="tab {{ strtolower($category->name) }}">{{ $category->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

// the posts loop
@foreach($blog_categories as $category)
                       
    @foreach($category->blog_post as $blog)
         <div class="col-md-4 post {{ strtolower($category->name) }}">
              <p>{!! $blog->text !!}</p>
         </div>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

so, how can I achieve that the `orderBy` works again as intented?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you're not looping for blogs, you're loops tow time for $blog_categories